# "No subscription found in the context" error when invoking Azure Powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I am trying to write some simple **Powershell** scripts to stop, start and restart our **Azure** web app. I can see that there are *cmdlets* called `Stop-AzWebApp`, `Start-AzWebApp` and `Restart-AzWebApp` that do this. The problem is they all require a parameter called **DefaultProfile** of type *Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.Core.IAzureContextContainer*. How do I get hold of this?

I have looked around for solutions but it seems confusing as there seem to be several ways of doing this including invoking `Connect-AzAccount`, but this requires multiple parameters (and I'm not sure which ones I need to supply).

Here is the error I get when I invoke `Get-AzSubscription` from our TFS build.

[image]

Here is the error I get when I invoke `Stop-AzWebApp` from our TFS build.

[image]

```
No subscription found in the context Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access the Azure subscription then run Connect-AzAccount to login
```

Here's the PS script I'm using.

```
$ResourceGroupName = "MyResourceGroup"
$Name = "MyWebAppName"

"Stopping web application " + $Name

"ResourceGroupName: " + $ResourceGroupName
"Name: " + $Name

$SubscriptionId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
"SubscriptionId is: " + $SubscriptionId

$Subscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
"Subscription : " + $Subscription

Stop-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $Name
```

What's the simplest way to start, stop and restart an Azure web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error, you need to run [`Connect-AzAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/Connect-AzAccount?view=azps-3.6.1) to login to azure powershell, but in TFS, you could not use the interactive way to login, so your option is to use the service principal to login, it is a non-interactive way.

Please follow the steps below.

1.[Register an AD App in azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application), then [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

2.Navigate to your subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add role assignment` -> seacrh for the name of the AD App and add it as a role e.g. `Owner/Contributor`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application).
[image]

3.In your script, use the command below to login, you can get the vaules in step 1, then run the command e.g. `Stop-AzWebApp`, it will work fine.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<Application-ID>"
$azureTenantId= "<Tenant-ID>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal 
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<Subscription-id>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try that out and see how I get on.

Comment: Finally got this working. I also found this article helped https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal. Thanks for your help. I will mark this as answer.